# Using a Parameter in a Bash Alias/Function

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a helpful bash alias/function.  I can't seem to get it to properly interpret the string parameters.

```
alias phpr="php -r '${*}'"
alias decode="php -r 'echo base64_decode($1);'"

function phpr ()
{
    php -r "${*}"
}

function decode ()
{
    php -r "echo base64_decode($1);"
}
```

an example of how Im trying to use decode and it failing:

```
decode "MT0xO2JhbGFuY2VfaXNfc2hvd249MDtiZXRfYW1vdW50PTE7YmV0X3R5cGU9MTE7ZmF2b3JpdGVfdHJhY2sxPUZSRTtmYXZvcml0ZV90cmFjazI9TU1BO2Zhdm9yaXRlX3RyYWNrMz1UQU07ZmF2b3JpdGVfdHJhY2s0PU1FRDtmYXZvcml0ZV90cmFjazU9QVFVO3dhZ2VyX3N0YXR1cz0wO2N1cnJlbnRUcmFjaz1GUkU7Y3VycmVudFJhY2U9NjtyYWNlRGF0ZT0yMDExLTA0LTI4O3JhY2V1cGRhdGVkPTs%3D"

PHP Warning:  base64_decode() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0
PHP   2. base64_decode() Command line code:1
```

I'm not sure when I'd use a function vs an alias for cases like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your alias - alias doesn't take parameters.  Have you tried `alias phpr="php -r"`?

For the function - it could be something being parsed in your string.  Double-quotes allow parsing, Single-quotes take the string verbatim.  You want the `$1` to be parsed, but include any whitespace, wo you want double-quotes around that.  But you can do single quotes for the rest of it:

```
function decode ()
{
    php -r 'echo base64_decode('"$1"');'
}
```

Note that this includes 4 single-quotes and 2 double-quotes.

**EDIT** Updated with Glenn's change.  If php needs the parameter to be in quotes, you may need to do:

```
function decode ()
{
    php -r 'echo base64_decode("'"$1"'");'
}
```

Note that this includes 4 single-quotes and 4 double-quotes.

Ah, shell scripting...

Comment: you probably need some double quotes for the php script: `php -r 'echo base64_decode"'"$1"'");'` -- if $1 is 'foo bar', then you get `php -r 'echo base64_decode("foo bar");'`

Comment: ah, good point @glenn.  I don't use php, so I'm not familiar with its needs.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tim.  It works perfectly.  It gives me insight into how to do the phpr one too (encapsulating the ' in ")

Comment: @Brombomb, when writing shell scripts, it's important to know the differences between the three escape mechanisms, and to remember that the quotes are simply toggles - you can enter and exit quote mode as many times as you want in a single line.  Full details would be a much longer post.  I'm pretty sure I've seen it documented somewhere.  If I find the page, I'll link it here.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer one part of your question straight away: Bash aliases cannot take arguments.

Comment: So then that'd be the use case between alias and function. Thanks